# How to add material "Slot List" to panel on my addon?

Tags: python, interface

How to add material "Slot List" to panel on my addon?

[image: how to add slots?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to get a widget of the main UI you can find how it looks like in the code. Very convenient.

In your case:

- right click on the dropdown to get the source:

  [image: rightClickToGetThesource]
- a message appears at the bottom on the main window:

  [image: message]
- open the Scripting workspace:

  [image: open Scripting workspace]
- in the text editor, open the script that has been added by the previous operation:

  [image: open script]
- go to the line with the red marker:

  [image: go to line]
- copy the relevant code block:

  [image: copy code]
- paste the code in the Draw() function of your own script and adjust it so that no variables get missing:

> ```
>  ob_type = # set your current object here
>  has_material_slots = True # do a test here
>
>  if ob_type != 'LIGHT':
>     row = layout.row()
>     row.enabled = has_material_slots
>     row.ui_units_x = 4
>     row.popover(panel="NODE_PT_material_slots")
> ```

- run your script:

[image: run Script]